# How to load Zend Guard Loader with PHP Debug build?

Tags: php

I am trying to add the Zend Guard Loader extension to my PHP debug build. 
This is the error message that I am recieving when executing php.exe:

> Failed loading ext\ZendLoader.dll 
>   Failed loading ext\php_opcache.dll

Zend Guard Loader is downloaded for PHP 5.6 from http://www.zend.com/en/products/loader/downloads#Windows

And this is the guide that I followed for installing it:

http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Guard/content/installing_zend_guard_loader.htm

I compiled PHP 5.6.30 on Windows 10 by following this guide:

https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

The build is configured with following parameters:

--disable-all --enable-cli --enable-debug --disable-zts

My php.ini can be found here: http://pastebin.com/fDyBeMep

Output from phpinfo() (without zend extensions) can be found here: http://pastebin.com/1XZu3Cm0

The files ZendLoader.dll and php_opcache.dll are in the ext folder.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: If u still looking for a php decompiler u can look for ioncube decoder. In the php.dll u will find a php opcode decompiler. Unfortunately in compiled form.  There also a paper explaining it (but without the decompiler part).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Betterdev. Did you happen to see the question about a PHP decompiler I posted, which got closed? Do you have a link to this paper? Is the php.dll a part of the paper, or something that I should look for on the web?

Comment: 1. Yes 2.https://www.syssec.rub.de/media/emma/veroeffentlichungen/2016/01/14/PHP-De-Protection_RAID15.pdf http://antiref.com/?https://media.blackhat.com/ad-12/Saher/bh-ad-12-stealing-from-thieves-Saher-slides.pdf 3. The .DLL is on the web. I did some reverse it looks like some work from the first paper. Imo it uses the opcode array (and deobfuscation) and a decompiler.

Comment: Thanks. I used that article to decrypt ZendGuard V7. It works. Just looking to decompile it into source code now. Will have a look at the ioncube decoder you mentioned. Didnt seem to find any for php 5.6 last time I looked.

Comment: There is none. It ends with php 5.3. But the opcode decompiler is in the php.dll.